# protractor browser.actions().mouseMove() not showing hover effects

Tags: protractor, mouseover

I am new to protractor and trying to add tests for a slider panel which is closed by default and hovering mouse over will open it and then there are a list of items on the slider panel to pick.

```
<div class="slider" [ngClass]="{ closed: state === 1, open: state === 2}" (click)="onClick($event)" (mouseover)="onMouseOver($event)" (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave($event)">
```

I tried multiple ways, none of them work.

**First attempt:**(no hover effect, ie, do nothing)

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('.slider.closed'))).perform();
```

**Second attempt:**( got an error: An invalid or illegal selector was specified)

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('[(mouseover)="onMouseOver($event)"]'))).perform();
```

**Third attempt:** (got an error: No element found using locator)

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('[mouseover="onMouseOver($event)"]'))).perform();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used webdriver and made it work.    `browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()',browser.driver.findElement(By.css('.slider')));`

Comment: how did mouseHover will work in this ? this is a click thing,, first we have to take the mouse over

Answer (score 4):

This should work, unless you have multiple elements with class `.slider`. At which point, you might try including a parent object, or another locator strategy.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove($('.slider')).perform();
```

Comment: It still does not work. I am using chrome browser (Version 48.0.2564.82 m). I think the element can be located, just there is no hover effect, that is, slider does not open. I need to make slider open first and then click the item in the slider panel. or you think there are other way i can just click the item in the panel.

Comment: Hi, Brine, thanks for your answer. I think it should work, but it just not work for my particular widget. I am not sure why. I did work around and made it work.   browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', browser.driver.findElement(By.css('.slider')));

Answer (score 2):

I just have the same problem, after 2 hours, I found this work for me:

src: [java mouse over using javascript](http://automation-home.blogspot.com/2015/04/java-webdriver-mouseover-using-javascript.html)

```
 let loginElement = await driver.findElement(By.id('header-user'));
    let strJavaScript = "var element = arguments[0];"
    + "var mouseEventObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"
    + "mouseEventObj.initEvent( 'mouseover', true, true );"
    + "element.dispatchEvent(mouseEventObj);";
    await driver.executeScript(strJavaScript, loginElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when run tests with firefox
and find out a solution as below

```
if (browser.isFirefox) {
 var script = `if(document.createEvent) {
      var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false);
      arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj); 
    } else if (document.createEventObject) { 
      arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover'); 
    }`;
  browser.executeScript(script, elm.getWebElement());
  return elm.click();
} else {
return browser.actions()
  .mouseMove(elm.getWebElement())
  .click()
  .perform();
}
```

Test with:
Protractor: 5.1.1
Selenium: 3.4.0