# Protractor - Chromium 89 - w3c compliance and browser.actions

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a test which needs to click on a checkbox.
If I simply do `$('.my-cb').click()` I get
`Element <input type="checkbox" > is not clickable at point (...). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>`

That's why I do

```
browser.actions().mouseMove($('.my-cb')).click().perform()
```

Because of using `browser.actions` I needed to disable w3c compliance for chrome, as it's started failing back then with a version 75.X. At this time it has worked fine.

```
config.capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--disable-web-security', '--ignore-certificate-errors'],
    w3c: false,
  },
  ...
}
```

Now I've updated Chrome 75 -> 89.
While this works on my local Windows environment, it fails on the linux CI with
`Failed: unknown command: Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode`

So in fact what I need is to disable w3c compliance (as the above config stopped working) or to replace `browser.actions()` calls.
I've been searching for other ways of disabling w3c compliance in Chrome 89, but found nothing useful. Only other people experiencing the same problem.

```
"@angular/core": "^10.2.4",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",

chromedriver_89.0.4389.23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because on top of your element there is a wrapping element. It can even be invisible. But protractor can't click on it. What you can do is top declare js click (inject script in console). and then just click any element directly. This `jsClick` doesn't care about interactivity and visibility of the element you're clicking

```
    let jsClick = ($element) => browser.executeScript(
        "arguments[0].click();",
        $element.getWebElement()
    );

    let $option = $("option[value='395']");

    await jsClick($option);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did work for the checkbox. However when using this with the dropdowns another issue appears - randomly some of the dropdowns don't extend on time, and their option can't be found. 
`NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("mat-option .mat-option-text", "Yes")`


I've tried to use this code, but the result is the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44595703/1913596

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> 1. It turned out that my selenium server was upgraded and now the proper way to pass the chrome config was to use `'goog:chromeOptions'` insted of `chromeOptions`. This way I was able to disable w3c compliance again.
>
>    ```
>    'goog:chromeOptions': {
>      args: ['--disable-web-security', '--ignore-certificate-errors'],
>      w3c: false,
>    },
>    ```
> 2. In the meantime, combining @Sergey Pleshakov answer with some other answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44595703/1913596, I was able to achieve pretty good results switching from `browser.actions` usage to plain `browser.executeScript` usage. The `jsClick` proposed by @Sergey Pleshakov worked nice for the checkboxes, but for the dropdowns I needed to do much more.
>
> As my test is clicking through a big form, with multiple tabs, waiting for the options to roll down and roll up was necessary. In the end I've finished with such code:
>
> ```
> export const jsClick = $element =>
>  browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].click();', $element.getWebElement())
>
> export const jsMove = async $element => {
>  await browser.executeScript(
>    `if(document.createEvent) {
>      var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
>      evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false);
>      arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj); 
>    } else if (document.createEventObject) { 
>      arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover'); 
>    }`,
>    $element.getWebElement()
>  )
>  return browser.sleep(1000)
> }
>
> export const scrollIntoView = function(el) {
>  return browser.executeScript(function(el) {
>    el.scrollIntoView()
>  }, el.getWebElement())
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> await scrollIntoView(input)
> await jsMove(input)
> await browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(input), 5000, >WAITING_TOO_LONG_FOR_ELEMENT)
> await input.click()
>
> const optionByCss = by.cssContainingText('mat-option .mat-option-text', value);
> await browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(element(optionByCss)), 5000, >WAITING_TOO_LONG_FOR_ELEMENT)
> const option = await element(optionByCss)
> await jsMove(option)
> await option.click()
> await browser.wait(until.invisibilityOf(element(optionByCss)), 5000, >WAITING_TOO_LONG_FOR_ELEMENT)
> ```
>
> However this is pretty sad to do such over complication while one could just use `browser.actions().mouseMove($('.cls')).click().perform()` in Chrome. I don't really understand why this API is not ported to other browsers.