# perform mouse hover on a svg pie chart element not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, svg, protractor

Using protractor I am trying to perform mouse hover on a svg pie chart element and the mouse hover is not working at all. No error is also displayed for me. I am trying to read a text that displayed within the chare when mouse hover on the element

```
  let emailBatchitems = element.all(by.xpath("//div[contains(@class,\"DonutChart_donut-legend-wrapper\")]/*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='path']"))
   emailBatchitems.map(function(emailBatchelem){
      browser.actions().mouseMove(emailBatchelem).perform();
      let emailBatchName = element.all(by.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'DonutChart_donut-legend-wrapper')]//*[local-name()='text']"))
      emailBatchName.getText().then((text) => {
           console.log("The email batch name is " + text)
      })
    })
```

source
screenshots

Before mousehover
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY0GE.png

after mousehover
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0due2.png

Comment: Please update your question with a functioning [mcve].

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue using the method mentioned in this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231434/protractor-browser-actions-mousemove-not-showing-hover-effects

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `<svg>` with a span tag and pass the `id` to the span tag and try to click on that element with the help of `id`